# ArrowIndicator Event Handling in Dojo

Tags: events, dojo, event-handling, gauge

I have a gauge chart which has one arrowIndicator.
Im trying to capture the value change event on the arrowIndicator. I tried dojo.connect() and on() methods to set the event handler for my gauge but failed both times.
This is what I did...

```
var arrow = new dojox.gauges.AnalogArrowIndicator({....});

dojo.connect(arrow, 'change', handlerFunction);
```

AND

```
var arrow = new dojox.gauges.AnalogArrowIndicator({....});
define(["dojo/on"], function(on){
on(arrow, "change", myHandleFunction);
});
```

I don't get any error message or anything...
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the valuechange event is exposed at the guage chart level:

```
dojo.connect(gauge.indicators[0], "valueChanged", dojo.hitch(gauge, function(){
  //new value is in this.indicators[0].value
}));
```

where, gauge is the jsid or js variable holding the gauge dijit

depending on how you are adding the indicators, it might be indicators[1] or similar

Comment: Awesome!! This are my first steps in Dojo and its kinda confusing. THANKS!

Comment: Great - happy to help. Yes, there is lots in there and though the dojo developers try to document things, there are hidden features/gems still there to be discovered :-).. A combination of dojo nightly tests, looking into the source code and the wiki/docs will equip you with all you need - also dojo is completely extensible, so you can override portions of the widgets and extend them..

Comment: Since we're on the subject. How do I go about changing the gauge value programmatically? I tried both gauge.indicators[0].set('value', myValue) and gauge.set('value', myValue)

Comment: actually the indicator seems to expose an update() method. See http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gauges/tests/test_AnalogGaugeWidget.html for an example of setting a value. Also the tests at: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gauges/tests/ is a good place to look for features and examples

Comment: nothing... I mean maybe I'm missing some update on rendering or something. I debugged and I see value = myValue on the indicator object but the gauge chart doesn't move to myValue at all. Maybe some refresh or update missing?